# limit number of backup files

Tags: gnucash

Gnucash defaults limit of backup file to days instead of number of files, so if gnucash is opened for several hours, there could be many backup files. Is there a way to limit the backup of files to a number of files instead of days? So I can specify I want to keep 5 backup files instead of 3 days of backup files (that could end up to few hundred of files in 3 days!!)

Comment: Why does it matter how many backups there are (presuming they go into a dedicated "gnucash_backups" directory)?

Comment: Because I put the gnucash files in a backup dir, where other files that I want to save are located, so when I do a backup, I need to clean the Gnucash files before doing a backup, if there are less files, I could just back them up.

Comment: Why not put the gnucash backups in their own dedicated subdirectory *under* your backup dir?

Comment: 3 files per hour would be the average for a bit under 240 files over 3 days. Are you prepared to keep just the last hour of work backed up? If you made a mistake 2 hours ago, you couldn’t roll back because that backup would have been deleted to keep the number of files down to just 3.

Comment: What you can do is space out your backups. [Here](https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2014-March/053881.html) is a conversation you might find interesting. But backups are so important that I don’t think it would be a good idea to actively work towards reducing their effectiveness - hence just the link rather than an ‘answer’.

Comment: @RonJohn, even doing this way, I'll still have problem of a considerable amount of "duplicate" backed up files, therefore still need to clean up before doing my backup.

Comment: @Lawrence, I used to work with Quicken in Windows, and I remembered in there the user can choose how many copies of backup to keep (I'm pretty sure that the file is backed up when closed and if there's a change), so it keeps a manageable number of backup copies, which I found more reasonable, and not keep number of auto-save as backup. I'm afraid this is a philosophical discussion, all depends on the idea of developer when s/he designed this apps.

Comment: I have the same issue with the Gramps genealogy program, and accept it.  (Those files are *big*, too.)

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question. but if you work out of a temporary folder, you can rename and copy the main file back to the archives whenever you like. Then delete the temporary folder. Doing it manually allows you to do the backups at your own pace.

Comment: @RonJohn, agreed, that's why I'm saying it's a philosophical discussion, I'm grateful to the developers for this nice open source apps. Just as a clarification, I used to work at a medium size bank as IT support, and in there we do a daily backup and not every few minutes/hours, for a bank with daily transactions over thousands, their strategy is do a daily backup and not hourly. Please check [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.arcf000/s6178.htm) for more information.

Comment: @Lawrence, yes, correct, the solution I'm using at this moment is just delete those extra files manually before doing my backup, so I won't have unneeded files in my backup.

Comment: @michaelbr you don't back up transactions every hour (or even 15 minutes)???  As a DBA, that **really concerns me**.

Comment: @RonJohn there's a distinction between backup and save changes, depending on how critical are your changes, you should save it every few seconds, even a minute, but for backup, DBA will define what's the reasonable frequency/amount of copies to keep, and normally those backups are kept outside on a rotational basis.

Comment: @michaelbr "there's a distinction between backup and save changes".  I've been a DBA long enough to know that **no**, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure much about GnuCash's workings by selecting *Preferences* on the GnuCash *Edit* menu.

On the *General* page of Preferences, you can choose to:

1. Set the time interval at which GnuCash will auto-save your file.  You could make it every 2 minutes (not recommended), or every 10 hours (also not recommended).  Or you could turn off auto-save altogether (definitely not recommended).
2. Specify the number of days for which backups of your data files and log files should be retained in the backups folder (0 days, 1 day, 999 days, or pretty much anything in between).

With these two options you can **severely limit** the number of backup files that are generated, and **drastically reduce** the period for which those files are retained.

As others have pointed out in comments, imposing these limits is **not necessarily a good idea**.  But the software allows it, if that's your choice.